# Auto populate one field based on another javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm not very familiar with javascript, but trying to populate username field with what the user types into the email field. Also don't want user to be able to edit username field after being auto populated from the email field. Will 'disable' still allow JS to work?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var first = document.getElementById('email'),
    second = document.getElementById('username');

    first.onkeyup = function () { 
        second.value = first.value;
    };
</script>
```

my form has a number of fields. One of them has ID and name of 'username' and another field has name and ID of 'email'. Why can't I get this to work? is my JS syntax wrong?

Comment: Move the script to the bottom of the page. My guess is that the form elements don't exist at the time the script is called. HTML and JavaScript is executed from the top down

Comment: Are you getting any errors? I suspect you have this code placed before the input fields, in your HTML?

Comment: wrap your code in `document.onload = function(){ ... }`.

Comment: The code is fine (Albeit a little strange that you declare var for `first` but not for `second`). If you disable the input you can still access it with javascript. Check your console (usually press f12) for error messages.

Comment: @judgeja note the comma, he doesnt need var for second.

Comment: thanks jasonscript. Moved to bottom of page and works

Comment: I must be going blind, I could have sworn that was a semi-colon.

Answer (score 0):

Jasonscript pointed out that I needed to have script at bottom of page. Moved it and it works.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible your issue is being cause by calling the JavaScript before the html elements have been created. A simple solution is to place your JS at the bottom of the page.

```
<html>
   <head>
   </head>
   <body>

      --ALL YOUR HTML HERE--

      <script type="text/javascript">
         var first = document.getElementById('email'),
         second = document.getElementById('username');

         first.onkeyup = function () { 
            second.value = first.value;
         };
      </script>
   </body>
</html>
```